Analogy between Algebraic Geometry and Algebraic Number Theory definitions (Picard Group, Ramification index, etc)
I am currently reading Arithmetic of Elliptic Curve by Silverman. The first two chapters covers some basic concept and definitions in Algebraic Geometry. The author was hinting that some of the definitions are highly related to Algebraic number theory. However, I couldn't really see the analogy. In particular, there are a few things that I am particularly confused about.
Before anything, I want to say that I am an absolute novice in both Algebraic Number Theory and Algebraic Geometry, so I apologize in advance if there are any factually incorrect statements in my question, and I would appreciate any form of feedback.

The ramification index. From Algebraic number theory, for a number field $K$ of degree $n$, we can factor as follow
$$
p \mathbb{Z}_K = {\mathfrak{p}_1}^{e_1}{\mathfrak{p}_2}^{e_2} \ldots  {\mathfrak{p}_r}^{e_r}
$$
Let $f_i = [\mathbb{Z}_K/\mathfrak{p}_i: \mathbb{F}_p]$. Then $n = \sum_{i=1}^{r} e_i f_i$. There is a similar thing in Algebraic Geometry. Let $\phi: C_1 \to C_2$ be a nonconstant rational map between two smooth curves. For a point $P$ on $C_1$, we define the ramification index of $\phi$ at $P$ to be
$$
e_\phi(P) = \mathrm{ord}(\phi^{*} t_{\phi(P)})
$$
Just to make things easier: $\phi^*$ is the injection of functions fields induced by $\phi$:
$$
\phi^*(f) = f \circ \phi \quad \text{and} \quad \phi^*: K(C_2) \to K(C_1)
$$
and $t_{\phi(P)}$ is the uniformizer of $C_2$ at $\phi(P)$. A proposition states that for every $Q$ on $C_2$,
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{P \in \phi^{-1}(Q)} e_\phi(P) = \deg \phi = [K(C_1): \phi^*K(C_2)]
\end{equation*}
This is extremely similar to the $[K: \mathbb{Q}] = \sum e_if_i$. I am curious about the analogy between the definition of the ramification index and the prime factorization. What is the intuition behind the summation that gives the degree of the map? What does it really mean for a curve to be unramified at a point (all the ramification indices are >1), and how is it related to a prime being unramified?

The Divisors and Picard Group. Let
$$
\mathrm{div}(f) = \sum_{P \in C} \mathrm{ord}_P(f)(P) \quad \text{and} \quad \mathrm{div}: \bar{K}(C)^{\times} \to \mathrm{Div}(C)
$$
Abstractly, I understand that this is a map that sends functions in the function field to a formal sum of points on the curve. The author noted that "It is analogous to the map that sends an ele-
ment of a number field to the corresponding fractional ideal." I totally don't get the connection between divisors and fractional ideals. Then, the Picard group is defined as
$$
\mathrm{P}(C) = \frac{\mathrm{Div}(C)}{\{\text{principal divisors}\}} \quad \text{and} \quad \mathrm{P}^0(C) = \frac{\mathrm{Div}^0(C)}{\{\text{principal divisors}\}}
$$
where $\mathrm{Div}^0(C)$ is all the divisors with degree zero. My best guess for this is that $\mathrm{Pic}(C)$ is analogous to the definition of class groups of a number $K$, but what's so special about $\mathrm{Pic}^0(C)$? Finally, the author included an exact sequence
$$
1 \to \bar{K}^\times \to \bar{K}(C)^\times \to \mathrm{Div}^0(C) \to \mathrm{Pic}^0(C) \to 0
$$
which should be analogous to the fundamental exact sequence in algebraic number theory. However, I am not seeing any analogy. In addition, I am confused why it's $\mathrm{Pic}^0(C)$ instead of $\mathrm{Pic}(C)$ because in the algebraic number theory exact sequence, we had the ideal class group which should correspond to $\mathrm{Pic}(C)$.


Lastly, if any of these questions are too long to be a stack exchange answer, feel free to leave references that might help answer these questions. :-)

Do you know the fact that the ring of functions on a smooth affine algebraic curve is a Dedekind domain?

@ZhenLin I don't know this as a fact but it does make sense

It's worthwhile to point out that to get the analog of "degree of divisor" on number fields, one need to "add a point at infinity", for which higher dimensional case were studied in Arakelov geometry.

The definitions you are encountering in algebraic geometry and algebraic number theory are related through what is commonly called the function field analogy. Here I will go through the details of this analogy as it relates to the specific constructions you asked about, and I will summarize the analogy in a table following this. At the end I will say a few words about how some of these constructions can be realized not merely analogously, but as special instances of a more general theory.


The Function Field Analogy
Given a (perfect) field $k$ there is a correspondence between smooth projective curves $C/k$ and function fields (purely transcendental extensions of transcendence degree one) $K/k$. As Silverman alludes to, this correspondence allows us to talk about the geometry of curves in such a way that it is almost as if we are doing algebraic number theory. In fact, Rosen's fabulous book Number Theory in Function Fields states and proves "geometric" theorems such as Riemann-Roch and the Weil conjectures for curves purely as theorems about the function fields themselves. When $k$ is a finite field, the analogy here becomes far stronger, to the point where some developments in algebraic number theory (most notably Iwasawa theory) were even inspired by the theory of function fields over finite fields.

Ramification indices
To see how the number theoretic and geometric ramification indices are the same thing, let's reframe the definition we have from algebraic number theory. Given a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of a number field $K$, we can consider the localization $(\mathcal{O}_K)_{(\mathfrak{p})}$, which is the subring of $K$ consisting of elements of the form $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$ ($\alpha,\beta \in \mathcal{O}_K$) such that $\beta \notin \mathfrak{p}$. This ring is a discrete valuation ring (DVR), so its only maximal ideal is $\mathfrak{p}_* = \mathfrak{p}(\mathcal{O}_K)_{(\mathfrak{p})}$ which is generated by any $\pi \in \mathfrak{p}_*\setminus \mathfrak{p}_*^2$. Given any $\alpha \in K^\times$ there is a unique factorization
$$\alpha\mathcal{O}_K = \mathfrak{p}_1^{v_1}\cdots\mathfrak{p}_n^{v_n}$$
where each $\mathfrak{p}_i$ is a prime and $v_i \in \mathbb{Z}$. As any DVR is a principal ideal domain and thus a UFD, we can also factor $\alpha$ uniquely in terms of primes in the localization $(\mathcal{O}_K)_{(\mathfrak{p})}$. However, as there is only one prime (the chosen uniformizer $\pi$), we have a factorization $\alpha = u\pi^k$ where $u \in (\mathcal{O}_K)_{(\mathfrak{p})}^\times$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. The main property here is that the exponent $k$ in this factorization is exactly the exponent on $\mathfrak{p}$ in the previous factorization of $\alpha$ into prime ideals. The idea being, we can define the ramification index $e(\mathfrak{p}|p)$ by taking the power of $\pi$ in the factorization of $p$ in the localization $(\mathcal{O}_K)_{(\mathfrak{p})}$, rather than considering the full factorization of $p\mathcal{O}_K$ into prime ideals.
Compare this to the definition of the ramification index $e_\phi(P)$: we consider the map of function fields $\phi^* : K(C_2) \to K(C_1)$. By the previously mentioned correspondence, we can just as well think of this as an extension of function fields $L/K$. Unlike the number field case, there isn't immediately a clear notion of a ring of integers for $L$ or $K$. We can make a definition that would work, but it's not necessary here. Instead we directly define a prime of $K$ (resp. $L$) as a DVR $\mathcal{O} \subset K$ with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ such that $\mathrm{Frac}(\mathcal{O}) = K$ (notice that this exactly describes the localizations $(\mathcal{O}_K)_{(\mathfrak{p})}$ from the number field case). The upshot here is that there is a direct correspondence between these primes and points on the curves $P \in C_1$ (resp. $C_2$). Now given a point $P \in C_1$ and a nonconstant rational map $\phi : C_1 \to C_2$, the point $\phi(P) \in C_2$ gives us a prime $k[C_2]_{\phi(P)} \subset k(C_2) = K$. Arithmetically, we can choose any uniformizer as they will all yield the same factorization so we fix such an element $t_{\phi(P)}$. Now, the point $P \in C_1$ similarly gives us a prime $k[C_1]_P \subset k(C_1) = L$, and as discussed in the number field case we can consider the power of a fixed uniformizer $t_P$ in the factorization of $t_{\phi(P)}$ in $k[C_1]_P$. Taking $k = \bar{K}$, this is precisely the ramification index $e_\phi(P)$ that Silverman has defined!

The degree formula Silverman gives is in general only true over an algebraically closed field, and as stated in the previous paragraphs his definition of ramification is restricted to this setting. For an arbitrary field $k$, we define inertial indices $f_\phi(P)$ as follows: The points $P \in C_1$ and $\phi(P) \in C_2$ give us DVRs $k[C_1]_P$ and $k[C_2]_{\phi(P)}$ with maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}_P$ and $\mathfrak{m}_{\phi(P)}$, respectively. The map $\phi^* : k(C_2) \to k(C_1)$ gives rise to a map between the residue fields $\kappa(\phi(P)) \to \kappa(P)$, where $\kappa(P) = k[C_1]/\mathfrak{m}_P$ (and similar for $\kappa(\phi(P))$). This map makes $\kappa(P)$ a finite extension of $\kappa(\phi(P))$, and the degree of this extension is our inertial index $f_\phi(P)$. Since our correspondence between curves and function fields goes both ways, the points $\phi^{-1}(Q)$ for any $Q \in C_2$ are in correspondence with the primes of $k(C_1)$ lying over $k[C_2]_Q$. Just as with number fields, we have the formula
$$\sum_{\mathfrak{P}|\mathfrak{m}_Q} e(\mathfrak{P}|\mathfrak{m}_Q)f(\mathfrak{P}|\mathfrak{m}_Q) = \sum_{P \in \phi^{-1}(Q)} e_\phi(P)f_\phi(P) = [k(C_1) : k(C_2)].$$
These formulas are the same, being part of a more general theory of primes in extensions of Dedekind domains (and as with ramification, we can also define inertial indices in the number field setting by looking solely at localizations). As a consequence of the Nullstellensatz, the residue fields $\kappa(P)$ are finite extensions of $k$, so when $k$ is algebraically closed we have $\kappa(P) = \kappa(\phi(P)) = k$, so all inertial indices $f_\phi(P)$ are $1$. This gives us the formula from Silverman.

The Picard Group
The correct analogy to the ideal class group here is actually $\mathrm{Pic}(C)$, not $\mathrm{Pic}^0(C)$. The reasoning here is "geometric", as both the Picard group and ideal class group are special cases of the Picard group of a scheme. $\mathrm{Pic}^0(C)$ holds a lot of importance in algebraic geometry, as it gives rise to what is known as the Jacobian variety of $C$; unfortunately, I do not know of an analogy to this in algebraic number theory. Nevertheless, both of the following sequences are exact:
$$1 \to k^\times \to k(C)^\times \to \mathrm{Div}(C) \to \mathrm{Pic}(C) \to 0$$
$$1 \to k^\times \to k(C)^\times \to \mathrm{Div}^0(C) \to \mathrm{Pic}^0(C) \to 0.$$
As you noted, these are very analogous to the fundamental exact sequence from algebraic number theory:
$$1 \to \mathcal{O}_K^\times \to K^\times \to J_K \to \mathrm{Cl}_K \to 0.$$
Recall that the fractional ideals of $K$ can, as a consequence of unique factorization of ideals, be viewed as elements of the free abelian group $\bigoplus_{\mathfrak{p}} \mathbb{Z}[\mathfrak{p}]$ on the primes of $K$. Compare this with the definition of $\mathrm{Div}(C) = \bigoplus_P \mathbb{Z}[P]$. Moreover, if we view the ring $k[C]$ as the "ring of integers" of $k$ (which is justified for nice curves), we actually have $k[C]^\times = k^\times$, so the terms of the exact sequences are in some sense identical. Note however that this does not mean that $\mathrm{Pic}(C)$ is the ideal class group of $k[C]$. There are contributions from points at infinity that the ideal class group misses.

As mentioned, here I leave as a reference a table summarizing some of the correspondences/analogies between curves, function fields, and number fields.
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
\text{Smooth projective curves } C/k & \iff & \text{Function fields } K/k & \text{Number fields } L/\mathbb{Q}\\ \hline
\text{Points } P \in C(\bar{k})/\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{k}/k) & \longleftrightarrow & \text{Primes } \mathcal{O} \subset K & \text{Primes } \mathfrak{p} \subset \mathcal O_L\\
|\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{k}/k)\cdot P| & =\!= & [\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m} : k] & f(\mathfrak{p}|p) = [\mathcal{O}_L/\mathfrak{p} : \mathbb{F}_p] \\
\text{Nonconstant rational maps } C_1 \to C_2 & \longleftrightarrow & \text{Finite Extensions } K'/K & \text{Finite extensions } L'/L\\
\text{Divisors } D = \sum_P n(P)[P] \in \bigoplus_P \mathbb{Z}[P] & \longleftrightarrow & \text{Elements } A \in \bigoplus_{\mathcal O} \mathbb{Z} [\mathcal{O}] & \text{Elements } B \in \bigoplus_{\mathfrak p} \mathbb{Z}[\mathfrak p]\\
\text{Principal divisors } \mathrm{div}(f) & \longleftrightarrow & \text{Elements } f \in K^\times & \text{Fractional ideals } \frac{\alpha}{\beta}\mathcal{O}_L\\
\text{Picard group } \mathrm{Pic}(C/k) & \longleftrightarrow & \text{Class group } \mathrm{Cl}_K = \mathrm{Div}(K)/\mathcal{P}(K) & \text{Ideal class group } \mathrm{Cl}_K
\end{array}


Geometric Perspective
Lastly, I want to say a few words about the "geometric" perspective that really unifies the ideas discussed above from algebraic geometry and algebraic number theory. Just as we treated curves as if we were doing number theory, we may also study arithmetic in number fields in a geometric manner by thinking about schemes. In place of the number field $K$, we might consider the affine scheme $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_K$; the primes of $K$ are now the points in $\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_K$. For any (reasonable) scheme, we can define its Picard group, and as I alluded to earlier, the ideal class group of $K$ is in fact the Picard group of $\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_K$, and as the name might suggest, $\mathrm{Pic}(C)$ is the Picard group of the projective scheme $\operatorname{Proj} k[C]$. Further, ramification in number fields can be interpreted as a ramified map $\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_L \to \operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_K$ (where the degree of this map is precisely $[L:K]$). Geometrically, we might visualize ramification in the following depiction of the cover $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}] \to \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$:

Over most points in $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$, we have a branched covering i.e. two distinct points map to one. At almost all other points, there is a single point mapping down; this is inertia and is reflective of the fact that the residue fields are not algebraically closed. That is, morally, there should be two points mapping down to our chosen point in $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$, but these points actually "live" in an algebraic extension and are Galois conjugate, so to the base they look like one point. Finally, over $5$, there is a thicker "double point" which is the ramification; here there should again be two points mapping to $5$, but now these points coincide and the cover "doubles up on itself". You might thus think of the equation $\sum_{\mathfrak{P}|\mathfrak{p}} e(\mathfrak{P}|\mathfrak{p})f(\mathfrak{P}|\mathfrak{p}) = [L:K]$ as representing the idea that in some sense, there are always $[L:K]$ points of $\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_L$ mapping to any given $\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_K$.

Some references
I'll finish off by listing a few references for this material.

Lorenzini's book An Invitation to Arithmetic Geometry simultaneously covers geometry of curves and algebraic number theory, so this is a great introductory source which develops the analogies between curves and number fields side by side.
I mentioned Rosen's book covers a lot of the theory of curves from a purely number-theoretic approach. He also treats (as the name suggests) number theory in function fields, and occasionally remarks on geometric interpretations of this theory.
For scheme-theoretic algebraic geometry, there are numerous good references such as Hartshorne, Shafarevich, Vakil, Liu, Eisenbud, and Görtz-Wedhorn. I learned from Görtz-Wedhorn, so I know that book discusses numerous examples from algebraic number theory while treating schemes.


Excellent answer, thank you very much for your time !
